# How to split a string in one variable to create two variables?

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a list of names under variable `Names`:

```
Beckham, Benjamin  
Roy, Andrew R. 
Shaunson, David T.
```

How do I create two variables, one named `Last_name`, the other `First_name`?

Variable `Last_name` will be a list containing:

```
Beckham
Roy
Shaunson
```

Variable `First_name` will be a list containing:

```
Benjamin
Andrew R.
David T.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of what you want should lead you to look for a Stata command named (something like) `split`. Seek (with e.g. `search`) and you will find.

```
clear 
input str42 whatever 
"Beckham, Benjamin" 
"Roy, Andrew R."
"Shaunson, David T."
end 

split whatever, parse(,) 
rename (whatever?) (lastname firstname) 

list 

     +--------------------------------------------+
     |           whatever   lastname    firstname |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. |  Beckham, Benjamin    Beckham     Benjamin |
  2. |     Roy, Andrew R.        Roy    Andrew R. |
  3. | Shaunson, David T.   Shaunson     David T. |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, but your method is including the comma in the last name column. It is generating Beckham,  
Please let me know if my method is correct

Comment: It does not. Running the code @NickCox provided i get the exact same results as above (without a comma).

Comment: `split` discards parse characters, so the claim is incorrect, as @PearlySpencer confirms.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on it, and found an alternate solution:

```
generate inbet = strpos(Names, ",")
generate str1 Last_name = "" 
replace Last_name = substr(inbet,1,inbet - 1)
generate str1 First_name = "" 
replace First_name = substr(Name,inbet + 1,.)
```

Comment: You can shorten your code (which has a mistake) to: `generate Last_name = substr(Names, 1, strpos(Names, ",") - 1)` & `generate First_name = substr(Names,strpos(Names, ",") + 1, .)`

Comment: This is the method of `split` implemented at length.